# Is there a READ_SMS type permission just for eSIM

Tags: sms, permissions

I have an app that has READ_SMS permissions, but it doesn't "see" my eSIM, which is the one I want to READ_SMS.

Is there a special permission to see the incoming SMS for the eSIM?

[edit]
As per comments, if no special permission - then is there a variable/ parameter in the data of a new SMS object that has which SIM it was sent to?
Where is the *new SMS* object detailed, I can't find it on https://developer.android.com/

Thanks

My current phone
Pixel 6 Pro
Android v 13
Build TQ1A.230205.002

Comment: What device (especially it's Android version) do you use?

Comment: `READ_SMS` permission is required to get messages from Android's SMS database (which also includes SMS stored on SIM), whatever their source is. There is no special permission for eSIM. In fact Android won't let the apps directly interact with SIMs.

Comment: @Robert I have added the version :)

Comment: @IrfanLatif thanks - that is interesting - I am wondering if there is the "to" field in there then?
None of the Forward SMS apps seem to have it.

Comment: The standard columns are defined in [`Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns).

Comment: @AndrewT. please use this as the answer, so I can mark it as the answer :)
That, plus some AI chat got me to the answer....
But I want you to have the credit.

Comment: @CraigLambie to be honest, I'm not sure what question I answered since I don't think it answered the title, and I don't know what you're really looking for. So, feel free to post a self-answer explaining the detail! :)

Comment: @AndrewT. The answer is your comment "The standard columns are defined in Telephony.TextBasedSmsColumns"